# JFACE table viewer placeholder when contents are empty

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface, eclipse-pde

Using JFACE tableviewer can we have "No content available" just like place holder in JavaFx Tableview? Find the attached image to understand what I am trying to do.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for this in `TableViewer` or any of the other JFace viewers. You just have to leave the content empty or use a dummy single entry.

The Eclipse Outline view uses a `PageBook` control to show a different control for the 'An outline is not available' message instead of the outline tree. You could do something similar - but this won't show the table header. The `StackLayout` layout can also do this.